# Reading result into array in c

Tags: c, arrays

Just wondering what it is that I am doing wrong here?? It's very simple programming and I really should know this but just can't see the problem! Scanf is not reading the results of the equations into the respective positions in the array.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
int numbers[4];

printf("Please enter 2 numbers:\n");
scanf("%d %d", &numbers[0], &numbers[1]);

printf("Your 2 numbers added are: %d\n", numbers[0] + numbers[1]);
scanf("%d", &numbers[2]);

printf("Your 2 numbers subtracted are: %d\n", numbers[0] - numbers[1]);
scanf("%d", &numbers[3]);

printf("The results of your program are: %d, %d\n", &numbers[2], &numbers[3]);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you supposed to do `numbers[2] = numbers[0] + numbers[1];`? `scanf` is used to get input from a user not to get results from internal calculations.

Comment: That's exactly it Joachim hit the nail on the head. I had a suspicion that scanf was the problem. What is the best way to read directly from the console line though? I know I can just do numbers[2] = numbers[0]+numbers[1] but I'm just experimenting with different things

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you are piping the output of `stdout` back to `stdin`, you can't read back what you're printing on the output like you're attempting to-do here:

```
printf("Your 2 numbers added are: %d\n", numbers[0] + numbers[1]);
scanf("%d", &numbers[2]);
```

You should be doing this:

```
printf("Your 2 numbers added are: %d\n", numbers[2] = numbers[0] + numbers[1]);
printf("Your 2 numbers subtracted are: %d\n", numbers[3] = numbers[0] - numbers[1]);
```

Then on the final output, take out the address-of operators when printing your array values:

```
printf("The results of your program are: %d, %d\n", numbers[2], numbers[3]);
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for Jason thank you. And it's funny because I know this stuff. When working on more advanced things the basics can be tricky because I assume that the answer should be more difficult than it is! :)

Answer (score 3):

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    int main(void)
    {
    int numbers[4];

    printf("Please enter 2 numbers:\n");
    scanf("%d %d", &numbers[0], &numbers[1]);

    printf("Your 2 numbers added are: %d\n", numbers[0] + numbers[1]);
    numbers[2] = numbers[0] + numbers[1];

    printf("Your 2 numbers subtracted are: %d\n", numbers[0] - numbers[1]);
    numbers[3] =  numbers[0] - numbers[1];

    printf("The results of your program are: %d, %d\n", numbers[2], numbers[3]);

    return 0;
    }
```

Try this..

Answer (score 2):

Look at your last `printf` you have the &'s there when you don't want them.

Comment: And that error would have been found, if you use the `gcc` compiler, by the `-Wall` flag (which you should *always* use for `gcc`).

Answer (score 2):

```
printf("The results of your program are: %d, %d\n", &numbers[2], &numbers[3]);
```

should be

```
printf("The results of your program are: %d, %d\n", numbers[2], numbers[3]);
```

The `&` operator gets the address of the given variable. Here you just want to print the value stored in the variable and not the address of the variable.

OTOH, you don't need the `scanf()`'s for `number[2]` and `number[3]` as you are computing them! And the array size need not be `4` instead it can be `2`.

Answer (score 1):

```
printf("The results of your program are: %d, %d\n", numbers[2], numbers[3]);
```

this will give the garbage value in `number[2]` and `number[3]` because you are not giving any values to `number[2]` and `number[3]`.